# Is this server upgrade worth $10 per month?

Tags: web-hosting, webserver

At the moment I pay $110.95 per month for the following:

```
Pentium 4 x 2.4Ghz
2GB RAM
1 x 250GB HDD
100Mbps
cPanel
```

However I could upgrade? to this for $120 per month:

```
D510 1.66 GHz
2GB DDR2 RAM
1 x 500GB HDD
100Mbps
cPanel
```

For the price I'm paying do you think this is a good service? Would I see much benefit from the D510 1.66 over the P4?

I'm considering dropping cPanel as I'm close to the stage where I can manage most of these things through SSH.